# UITextfield fails to lose focus and line of code not executing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, focus

I have a `UITextField` which calls a PopOver inside a function called `popover()` on Editing Did Begin.

Inside of the popover the user selects an item from a tableview, and presses ok.

On the OK press `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` is executed.

The problem is once the popover is dismissed the textfield isn't losing focus, it remains selected.

I am using `resignFirstResponder` at the beginning of the function to dismiss the keyboard.

I've tried using `resignFirstResponder` at the end of the function and I've tried having another element `becomeFirstResponder` but none of it is causing the textfield to lose focus.

How do I drop focus from the text field, and is there a way to detect the loss of focus (or closing of the popover) in order to automatically execute `update()`

My Code follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


//declare variables
var popOverLocation: CGRect!

// Set outlets for all buttons
@IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {
   texttest.text = newValue
}

@IBOutlet weak var texttest: UITextField!


@IBAction func testtexttouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    texttest.resignFirstResponder()
    popOverLocation = texttest.frame
    popOver()
    texttest.text = newValue
    texttest.resignFirstResponder()
}

func update() {
    texttest.text = newValue

}

//function for creating the popover
func popOver() {

    //Read the height, and XY coordinates of the active button
    var h = popOverLocation.height
    var x = popOverLocation.origin.x
    var y = popOverLocation.origin.y + h

    //create the popover
    var popoverContent = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover") as UIViewController
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController! as UIPopoverPresentationController
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.delegate = self

    //set the size of the popover
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);

    //set the direction the popover arrow is allowed to point
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up

    //using the buttons coordinates set the location of the popover
    popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(x,y,0,0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

Comment: Why are you using a UITextField if you are going to ignore user input?

Comment: I'm using the popover as a custom user input.  (Though with a way to detect the closing of the pop Over I could cheat and replace the text field with a button, then update the button text)

Comment: I would use a button or a label with a tap gesture recogniser, this will make more sense for what you want to achieve

Comment: When is testtexttouch called?

Comment: teesttexttouch is on edit did begin