# Failing to make a drop down selection menu on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, option-type, uipopover

I've been trying to get a drop down selection menu but running into issues at every turn.

The plan is to have "Select Input" box (`label`, `text` or `button`) and once clicked a popOver acting like a drop down allows the user to select one item from an array as the input.
This version contains a storyboard with 2 view controllers, the main view has only a `label` and a `button`. the other (Popover) has a `tableview`, `label` showing the current selection and an ok button.

I've got a working [`UIPopOver` (See code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157190/uitextfield-fails-to-lose-focus-and-line-of-code-not-executing) that was passing my desired value, but I was unable to get the keyboard to deactivate after the selection was made with a `UITextField`.

I've tried switching to a button, with the `button label` updating to the selected value on close, but for some reason in this method every value I returned caused an error.

Any my latest attempt was to use a `label` with an edit `button` next to it, allowing it to switch the `label`, but that is returning an optional error that I don't understand.

I am receiving the following error:
on `popOverLocation = editedField.frame`
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"
my print line shows  "Optional ("test")
followed by " Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I was previously receiving the same error attempting to set `TestLabel.text = newValue`, I've confirmed my outlets, but I've never seen this error related to labels before.

Am I going about this the wrong way?
I am open to completely trashing this code and trying another way, but I'm unsure which way to go.  My final project will include several of these fields which need options selected from arrays.

(Note: in this version of my code I've moved the `UITableviewController` and all code for the popover into a single View Controller along with the main interface. This was done for testing purposes)

My Code Follows:

```
import UIKit

var newValue = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

var arrayofstuff = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"]
var selection: String = ""
var popOverLocation: CGRect!

@IBOutlet weak var TestLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var selectionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var editedField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func editButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(TestLabel.text?)
    popOverLocation = editedField.frame
    popOver()
}
@IBAction func okButton(sender: AnyObject) {
                println(newValue)
  TestLabel.text = newValue
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}


@IBOutlet var test2: UILabel!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrayofstuff.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayofstuff[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")

    var currentrow = indexPath.row
    if currentrow == 0 {
        selection = arrayofstuff[0]
        selectionLabel.text = selection
        newValue = selection
        println(newValue)
    } else if currentrow == 1{
        selection = arrayofstuff[1]
        selectionLabel.text = selection
        newValue = selection
                    println(newValue)
    } else if currentrow == 2{
        selection = arrayofstuff[2]
        selectionLabel.text = selection
        newValue = selection
                    println(newValue)
    } else if currentrow == 3{
        selection = arrayofstuff[3]
        selectionLabel.text = selection
        newValue = selection
                    println(newValue)
    }
}


//function for creating the popover
func popOver() {

    //Read the height, and XY coordinates of the active button
    var h = popOverLocation.height
    var x = popOverLocation.origin.x
    var y = popOverLocation.origin.y + h

    //create the popover
    var popoverContent = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover") as UIViewController
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController! as UIPopoverPresentationController
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.delegate = self

    //set the size of the popover
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);

    //set the direction the popover arrow is allowed to point
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up

    //using the buttons coordinates set the location of the popover
    popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(x,y,0,0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Did you connect your outlets to the interface elements?

Comment: I did. I've even opened a new project and started over. Same result.

Comment: recheck connections. make sure testing app on iPad device or iPad simulator.